# How to calculate the average of each group in each column of a matrix?

Tags: matrix, group-by, mask, dolphindb

I have two matrices with the same dimension, “value“ and “mask“:

```
value=matrix( 100 200 100,200 100 200,100 200 100);

//output
col1  col2  col3 
--- --- ---
100 200 100
200 100 200
100 200 100
```

---

```
mask=matrix( 1 2 1,1 1 2,1 2 1);

//output
col1 col2 col3
-- -- --
1  1  1 
2  1  2 
1  2  1
```

Each column of the “mask“ matrix has two groups, “1“ and “2“.

I want to obtain the average value of each group in the corresponding column of the “value” matrix.

Expected result:

```
col1    col2    col3
100     150     100
200     200     200
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use DolphinDB V2.00 or higher, you can use the script below:

```
value=matrix( 100 200 100,200 100 200,100 200 100);
mask=matrix( 1 2 1,1 1 2,1 2 1);
each(def(v, m):v[groups(m, 'table').index].rowAvg(), value, mask);
```

If not, you can run the following script:

```
value=matrix(100 200 100,200 100 200,100 200 100)
mask=matrix(1 2 1,1 1 2,1 2 1)
each(def(v, m)->groupby(avg, v, m).avg,value,mask)
```

Then, you can get your expected result:

```
col1    col2    col3
100     150     100
200     200     200
```

It should be noted that DolphinDB adopts column-major order for matrices, therefore, the `each` function apply a function to each column.